# Design dynamo db data model role based access control in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I am learning DynamoDB and trying to implement role-based access control in DynamoDB. Access control is a huge part of the application.

ERD looks something like this:

[image]

**A little explanation:**

1. **Groups** will be defined to collectively assign the same **Rights** on **Sites** to **Users**
2. **Sites** are hierarchical(Sites -> Zones -> Locations )and **Right** on a **Site** higher up in the hierarchy automatically gives *Rights* for all **Sites** below it - but there is an option to "override" **Rights** for a specific **Site**
3. Every **Customer** has many **Users** and a **User** can be in multiple **CustomerAccounts**

**Basic Access patterns:**

Get account info by customer_id

Get account info by account_id

Load user info by user_name

Get customers that a user is a member of

Get/update groups a user is in

Get/update sites a user has access to

Get/update users in a group

Get/update sites in a group

How should customer, user, groups and rights be structured? A high-level idea would work. Looking to get basic direction as to which of these should be put together in a single table and what should the high-level structure be

Comment: Are you sure that dynamodb is good for that? It seems to me that you have well structured data model, thus regular relational database could be more suited.

Comment: -1. Which of the services could be the right fit for if not the entire application?

-2. May be for measurements because it's streaming data? or Timeseries would be a better pick for measurements?

-3. Does relational DB make more sense instead for the rest of the app? @Marcin